# Styling point displacement for 2 variables QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, style

I have a dataset with multiple sampling events that I want to style by season (or "temporada" in my attribute table) and "EP Chinook". Data is from a csv file.

I styled with point displacement to show multiple sampling events.

Then I used categorized render settings to show different seasons, and used size scale fields to show "EP Chinook"

[image]

The problem I am running into is the points are way too big. 
[image]

I have tried writing expressions to change the size but there is no geometry for diameter, which is what I want to show. Such as:

```
$area="EP Chinook"
```

but this just makes the size of the points stay the same.

I think the reason I am having problems with the points being so big is that the layer still needs to be written so that minimum values remain visible.

I am new to QGIS (about 2 months of self taught) and am coming off of a moderately novice background with ArcMap.

I think I have found another way to style my data that will be appropriate.
-different symbols for months
-graduated color scale for "EP Chinook"
-point displacement for multiple sampling events

However, this is a temporary fix; it would still be nice to label the points using the initial styling I asked about.

Comment: you have to set the units of your scale-field (mm, px, map units) and probably re-scale your values. (ie: the standard setting is millimeters, so if your values go as high as 1000, qgis draws you a 1.0m circle)

Comment: I changed to map units (I did not see any option for "px") and everything was too small to see without zooming in a ridiculous amount.

Comment: you need to rescale your values (new field or OTF) with `scale_exp(x, from_min, from_max, to_min, to_max, power)` to an appropriate range, depending on your unit setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression should evaluate to either the area of diameter of the symbols. So instead of:

```
$area = "EP Chinook"
```

Try something like:

```
"EP Chinook"/10.0
```

Ie, this will scale the value in the field by 1/10th. You'll need to experiment with different factors until it looks right.

Alternatively, if you can upgrade to QGIS >= 2.12 there's a handy "size assistant" option which helps you do this interactively.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward process:

**1)**
The engine needs a unit-system (mm, px, map units) to interpret the values:
[image: scr1]

Choose one fitting (or almost fitting) to your dataset, projection and map(-goal).

Means:
A dataset [10,35,20,55,2] will be hard to see/distinguish on a px-scale but somewhat right on a mm-scale.
map-units *may* fit, depending on your projection and map, ie.: 30° is a bigass circle, but an appropriate country-size on a world map. 30m is nothing from a 1:500'000 view, but spans about 1/4 NY-Block.

as example, size = "B" in map units:
EPSG:3857, so everything around 1m
[image: scr2]

and EPSG:4326, same dataset in deg.
[image: scr3]

**2)**
If you have found your unit-system, you can/need/want to refine the domain with:

```
scale_exp(x, from_min, from_max, to_min, to_max, power)
```

Find your current min/max and choose a new range and a fitting-curve   (ie.: power=1 for linear or higher/smaller than 1 for a slower or more rapid escalating curve).
You can do this either on-the-fly (better option, since scaling may take some try&error):
[image: scr4]

or - if you can't find it or your version lacks the functionality - via the field calculator:
[image: scr5]

Hope that helps.